# React datepicker short month how to display three letters only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi do you know how can I display "Dec" instead of "December" here , for this library https://reactdatepicker.com/
[image]

Comment: By using custom header

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, using the [Custom header](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-header):

```
() => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    return (
        <DatePicker
            renderCustomHeader={({
                monthDate,
                customHeaderCount,
                decreaseMonth,
                increaseMonth,
            }) => (
                <div>
                    <button
                        className={
                            "react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--previous"
                        }
                        style={customHeaderCount === 1 ? { visibility: "hidden" } : null}
                        onClick={decreaseMonth}
                    >
                        <span
                            className={
                                "react-datepicker__navigation-icon react-datepicker__navigation-icon--previous"
                            }
                        >
                            {"<"}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <span className="react-datepicker__current-month">
                        {monthDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
                            month: "short",
                            year: "numeric",
                        })}
                    </span>
                    <button
                        className={
                            "react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--next"
                        }
                        style={customHeaderCount === 1 ? { visibility: "hidden" } : null}
                        onClick={increaseMonth}
                    >
                        <span
                            className={
                                "react-datepicker__navigation-icon react-datepicker__navigation-icon--next"
                            }
                        >
                            {">"}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            )}
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        />
    );
};
```